# How to update value between specific xml tags, where input is string, Python?

Tags: python, xml

Consider I have a string that looks like the following below. It's type is string but it will always represents an xml document. I'm researching available python libraries for xml. How can I update a value in between 2 specific tags? What library would I be using for that?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PostTelemetryRequest xmlns:ns2="urn:com:onstar:global:common:schema:PostTelemetryData:1">
  <ns2:PartnerVehicles>
    <ns2:PartnerVehicle>
      <ns2:partnerNotificationID>251029655</ns2:partnerNotificationID>
    </ns2:PartnerVehicle>
  </ns2:PartnerVehicles>
</PostTelemetryRequest>
```

For instance, if the input is the string above how can I update the value between `<ns2:partnerNotificationID>` and `</ns2:partnerNotificationID>` tags to a new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the base code:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> s = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PostTelemetryRequest xmlns:ns2="urn:com:onstar:global:common:schema:PostTelemetryData:1">
  <ns2:PartnerVehicles>
    <ns2:PartnerVehicle>
      <ns2:partnerNotificationID>251029655</ns2:partnerNotificationID>
    </ns2:PartnerVehicle>
  </ns2:PartnerVehicles>
</PostTelemetryRequest>
"""
>>> root = ElementTree.fromstring(s)
>>> for e in root.iter():
...  if e.tag=='{urn:com:onstar:global:common:schema:PostTelemetryData:1}partnerNotificationID':
...   e.text='mytext'
... 
>>> etree.ElementTree.tostring(root)
b'<PostTelemetryRequest xmlns:ns0="urn:com:onstar:global:common:schema:PostTelemetryData:1">\n  <ns0:PartnerVehicles>\n    <ns0:PartnerVehicle>\n      <ns0:partnerNotificationID>mytext</ns0:partnerNotificationID>\n    </ns0:PartnerVehicle>\n  </ns0:PartnerVehicles>\n</PostTelemetryRequest>'
```